# UITableView individual cell reload like UIStepper in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistepper

Working an application like Swiggy.

1. In UITableview display the item and price.
2. When click the add button item count and amount want to increased, when click the minus button the count and amount want to decreased.
3. Increasing and decreasing should loaded in each cell separately

Here is my Code:

```
var vegListPrice = [130,
                        200,
                        345,
                        456,
                        120,
                        110,
                        345,
                        300,
                        160,
                        210]

var vegListName = ["Bhindi masala veggies recipes",
                       "Aloo matar veggie recipes",
                       "Dum aloo veggie recipes",
                       "Veg kurma veggie recipes",
                       "Lauki kofta veggie recipesss",
                       "Aloo gobi masala",
                       "Baingan bharta veggie recipes",
                       "Bharwan shimla mirch veggie recipes",
                       "Vegetable kadai veggie recipes.jpg",
                       "Aloo palak palak recipes"]

extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.vegListName.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:ItmCell = self.veglistTbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItmCell") as! ItmCell
        cell.nameLbl.text = vegListName[indexPath.row]
        cell.addLbl.text = "$" + String(vegListPrice[indexPath.row])
        cell.increaseBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.increaseBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(IncreasePressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
        cell.decreaseBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.decreaseBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(DecreasePressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 180
    }

    @objc func IncreasePressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let button = sender as? UIButton
        let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = veglistTbl.indexPath(for: cell!)
        print(indexPath?.row)


    }

    @objc func DecreasePressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
           let button = sender as? UIButton
           let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
           let indexPath = veglistTbl.indexPath(for: cell!)
           print(indexPath?.row)
       }
```

[image]

4. UITableCell Index got how to reload separately.
5. Click plus button and minus button the amount should be added, and count should increasing and decreasing like swiggy. How can achieve this. I tried UIStepper and KWStepper to achieve this but I can't achieve this. Any help to achieve this. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered in your question you already have the indexPath to be reloaded. So just reload that particular row using the below method:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```